# Azure Synapse pipeline - get array from CSV column with dash in column name

Tags: csv, pipeline, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am using a pipeline to get data from a CSV and compare it to a SQL table. I have data about groups coming from an API, which we're storing in SQL for reporting. One of the column names from the API is "group-id". I need to get all the values of this column and store them in an array variable for comparison with the SQL values. I get this error when I attempt to run the pipeline: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'activity('Get ids from Data Lake').output.['group-id']'","target":"pipeline/MyAPI_Groups_With_Check/runid/cfe57967-f7bc-48dc-ae2f-5bb92029488c","details":null,"error":null}.

What is the proper way to get the values of this column? Expression I'm trying is: activity('Get ids from Data Lake').output.['group-id']. The output of 'Get ids from Data Lake' is a CSV, and group-id is the name of one of the columns.

Comment: Can we have some representative sample data please?  And expected results.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your expression has an extra '.', please try this expression:`@activity('Get ids from Data Lake').output['group-id']`.